# Using primary key as value for dropdown

Tags: php, html, database, pear

I am using Pear PHP and HTML quickforms to create a dropdown, concatenate results and maintain them in a drop down.

Code that fetches the data and concatenates:

```
DO_Common::DebugLevel(1);
$stDO = DO_Common::factory('SoftwareTypes');
$lmDO = DO_Common::factory('LicenseMethods');
$tDO  = DO_Common::factory('sldSoftwareType');

$stDO->selectAdd();
$stDO->selectAdd('Title, Method, sldSoftwareType.Type, SoftwareTypes.ID');
$stDO->joinAdd($lmDO);
$stDO->joinAdd($tDO);
$stDO->whereAdd("SoftwareTypes.Flag <> 1");

$stDO->find();
$lmst = array();

while ($stDO->fetch())
{                
    $lmst[] =$stDO->ID .  "| " .  $stDO->Title . " | " . $stDO->Method . " | " .$stDO->Type ;                

    // $text = array_column($lmst[], $stDO->ID);
}
```

**Dropdown creation code:**

```
$ddlSoftwareType = $form->addElement('select', 'ddlSoftwareType', 'Software Type', $lmst, array('id' => "SoftwareTypeList", 'orderBy' => "Type", "OnChange" => "GetDetails();"));
```

Although this works perfectly I want to be able to add the ID of the original table as the value of the dropdown.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is it the PHP 5 rewrite that you are using, i.e. HTML_Quickform2?